# MediaScanner, onScanCompleted is not called

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-activity, android-mediascanner

I have a problem with MediaScanner. I use it to scan a single File with this code:

```
public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnectionClient {

private static final String TAG = "SingleMediaScanner";

public MediaScannerConnection mMs;
private String mFile;

public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, String s) {
    mFile = s;
    mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
    mMs.connect();
}

public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
    Log.d(TAG, "MediaScanner conectado");
    mMs.scanFile(mFile, null);
}

public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MediaScanner terminó de escanear");
    mMs.disconnect();
}
}
```

If I scan a file at the beginning of an activity (onCreate), it works perfect. The scanner is connected, it scans the file and after that, is completed.

But if I call the scanner and then I go to another activity, the MediaScanner leaks memory because it doesn't call the onScanCompleted method. And if I use unbindService() with the scanner before leaving the activity, the scanner doesn't work (the file doesn't appear in the gallery app).

I need to use the scanner when I leave the activity. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other ways to add the file to the Gallery by using the static scanFile() method or by sending a BroadCast. Normally these should suit your need fine. You only need a MediaScannerConnection if you need some control over the addition process.

I have written a blog post about how to use the other [methods to trigger the MediaScanner](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/).